# Extract list of indices from pandas dataframe for first and last match

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data:

```py
# example data

dt = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "idx": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    },
).assign(val=lambda x: range(len(x)))
```

I'd like to extract the following list:

```
[0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13]
```

So that I can display the following data:

```
    idx  val
0     1    0
2     1    2
3     2    3
6     2    6
7     3    7
9     3    9
10    4   10
13    4   13
```

my approach to this has been:

```py
last_elements = dt.index[~dt["idx"].duplicated(keep="last")]
first_elements = dt.index[~dt["idx"].duplicated(keep="first")]
print(
    dt.iloc[[num for lst in list(zip(first_elements, last_elements)) for num in lst], :]
)
```

But am unsure whether there's a better approach that I could take (I'm sure there is)

Comment: This is a nice way to do this!

Comment: you could be a bit more straightforward and do `dt[~dt["idx"].duplicated(keep="first")|~dt["idx"].duplicated(keep="last")]` but yeah `duplicated` is a good way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

groupby is not the worst option here

```
dt.groupby('idx').agg(['first','last'])
```

produces

```
val
    first   last
idx     
1   0   2
2   3   6
3   7   9
4   10  13
```

Comment: ah, thank you, I should make better use of `agg`, so thanks for pointing out a use here. `dt.groupby("idx").agg(["first", "last"]).to_numpy().flatten()` seems a reasonable approach